# test a promise with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, testing

I have this factory and her test:

```js
angular.module('testApp')
  .factory('bar', function ($q) {
    // Service logic
    // ...

    var meaningOfLife = 42;

    // Public API here
    return {
      someMethod: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        setTimeout(function() {
          deferred.resolve();
        }, 1000);

        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
  });


'use strict';

describe('Service: bar', function() {

  // load the service's module
  beforeEach(module('testApp'));

  it('should do something', function(done) {
    inject(function (bar) {
        var promise = bar.someMethod();
        promise.then(function(){
          expect(!!bar).toBe(true);
          done();
        });
      });
  });
});
```

The test returns this:

Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

I know replacing setTimeout with $timeout in the factory and adding $timeout.flush() in the test, it works.

However, I would like to understand how i can work this test with setTimeout instead of $timeout.

Comment: I think the problem is, that jasmine has no means of tracing that you are using setTimeout - so it thinks that something wrong is going on because the callback was not invoked in a reasonable amount of time.
Anyhow, why do you have to use setTimeout? It's much easier to test any component in angular if you rely on angular-internal services (like $timeout)

Comment: It was to simulate a case who didn't work. example: var deferred = $q.defer(); $q.resolve(); return deferred.promise; Thanks to @ryeballar, I found my solution removing the done call.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `setTimeout()` is not running in AngularJS's digest cycle. You should `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout`. Additionally, using jasmine's `done()` callback function isn't really suitable in this case since you can just flush out all queued deferred functions that are stored synchronously.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Br2Si1HbvDuTI7US04s6?p=preview)**

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
  .factory('bar', function ($q, $timeout) {
    // Service logic
    // ...

    var meaningOfLife = 42;

    // Public API here
    return {
      someMethod: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function() {
          deferred.resolve();
        }, 1000);

        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
  });


'use strict';

describe('Service: bar', function() {

  // load the service's module
  beforeEach(module('testApp'));

  it('should do something', function() {
    inject(function (bar, $timeout) {
        var promise = bar.someMethod();
        promise.then(function(){
          expect(!!bar).toBe(true);
        });
        // flush out queued deferred functions!
        $timeout.flush();
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `$timeout` service, Angular's wrapper for window.setTimeout

```
var timeoutPromise = $timeout(angular.noop, 1000);
return timeoutPromise;
```

For more information  see [AngularJS $timeout API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout).